# IOS7 - How to add Advertisement on my ios app without using iad, admon and other platform?

Tags: ios7, iad, ads

My company has his own marketing server and want to include ads in his mobil apps. How to achieve this without using third party platforms like iad admod, ect......
Is using a fixed uiview good idea? 
Can i use Toolbar?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `UIViewController` that you subclass. The `ViewController` will handle all the logic to get the ads from your server, then use it to show you ads.